# Javascript es6 filter on object key-value type

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, filter

My backend response was using Map as data type, when I received the response in javascript it becomes an object, something like a key-value combination json object below when I check from console

```
guests: Object
1: {id: 1, name: 'Mike', age: 16}
2: {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 33}
3: {id: 3, name: 'Jason', age: 25}
4: {id: 4, name: 'Tiger', age: 54}
```

well if I use `guests.filter(g => g.age > 20)` it wouldn't work because guests here is `not an array` but an `object` (like `Map` but still an object type in javascript), so how could I filter my `guest` object here?

Comment: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: Seems your backend should be using an array / List type instead of a Map unless those sequential numeric keys are significant

Answer (score 2):

Convert `guests` to an array using `Object.values()`, and then filter the array:

```js
const guests = {"1":{"id":1,"name":"Mike","age":16},"2":{"id":2,"name":"Tom","age":33},"3":{"id":3,"name":"Jason","age":25},"4":{"id":4,"name":"Tiger","age":54}}

const result = Object.values(guests)
  .filter(g => g.age > 20)
  
console.log(result)
```